# Why is my process suspended when there is nothing else active on the server?

Tags: sql-server

I have an `UPDATE` running and I know that even though it's updating only one field it's updating over 10 million records, but when the process that normally runs 9 minutes kept running 30 minutes later, I checked.

I ran `sp_WhoIsActive` and it returned all processes currently active on the server.  My process was the only one, but it's suspended.

I tried `sp_who2`.  Everything else is sleeping, but my process is in parallel mode and they are all suspended.

The last wait type is `PAGEIOLATCH_EX`.

Why would it be SUSPENDED if there is nothing else `RUNNABLE` on the server?

Comment: It caused by large I/O (http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/02/09/sql-server-pageiolatch_dt-pageiolatch_ex-pageiolatch_kp-pageiolatch_sh-pageiolatch_up-wait-type-day-9-of-28/), please check your disk system or replace with a faster disk

Comment: You can find out what your process is waiting on *right now* by looking in sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks for your session_id. That will lead you in the right direction.